Iterative Solvers for Linear Least Squares with Integer Constraints
The classical linear least squares problem reads $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|Ax-b\|^2_2$ and its solutions satisfy the normal equations $A^{\top}Ax = A^{\top}b$. A standard approach to solve the latter is to employ e.g. the conjugate gradient solver for the normal equations, which if initialized to zero results in the Moore-Penrose solution: $x^{+} = A^{+} b$. I am looking to efficiently solve a least squares problem, but this time with $x$ being constrained to a set of values $\mathcal{D} = \{t_0,\ldots,t_m\}$ (the solution can be approximate):
$$\min_{x\in\mathcal{D}^{\,n}} \|Ax-b\|^2_2.$$
For simplicity those can be just the integers $t_i = i$, but I in reality I care about the general problem (through a nonlinear remapping of $x$ they can be made the integers). At the moment I just solve the continuous problem and then round the values to the closes $t_i$. I want some (greedy) strategy to improve this slightly, e.g. accounting for the constraints in some way at every iteration. A simple idea is to project the solution to the feasible set at every iteration, but this seems too radical and I assume will spoil the conjugate gradient directions. Instead I assume that phasing in the constraints slowly with the iterations should produce better results. I think the latter corresponds to a relaxation of the problem of the form:
$$\min_{x\in[t_0,t_m]^n}\|Ax-b\|^2_2 + \lambda \rho(x),$$
where $\rho$ is some penalizing function that depends on $\mathcal{D}$, and $\lambda$ can be increased with the iterations in order to enforce the constraints more strongly.
Are there any known methods for this problem, or references I could look into? I am more concerned with keeping a similar efficiency as with the conjugate gradient solver compared to getting an incredibly accurate solution, so greedier strategies are welcome. Ideally a simple modification of the conjugate gradient to a nonlinear one would be best. I can't really tell what penalizers would be good however, and how to choose $\lambda$.
Edit: I realized that it is probably worth mentioning that $A$ is very large and very sparse, which is why I use the conjugate gradient for the normal equations and not QR or SVD. I also care about the solution up until some precision, hence the conjugate gradient for the normal equations allows me to stop early. For linear equality constraints the conjugate gradient also works well by modifying it to project the descent direction on the orthogonal subspace of the constraints (the form is as if it was preconditioned with a projection matrix). The issue is really that the constraints here are integer ones, which is why I am looking to relax this and introduce those as penalizers, and to apply a nonlinear conjugate gradient on the latter.
Edit2: I found a relevant paper:
Improved penalty algorithm for mixed integer PDE constrained optimization problems

This can be formulated and solved as a Mixed-Integer Second Order Cone Problem (MISOCP) or (perhaps less numerically robustly as a Mixed-Integer Quadratic Program (MIQP),, although not necessarily as efficiently as you'd like. Integer constraints are not computationally easy.
